# SPFx JQuery Dialog button click does not find public function

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I am new to TypeScript and SPFx development.

I have a jquery UI dialog box and a public function in the same class that makes some MSGRAPH calls after the button has been clicked.

The button click returns with error:

> this.addAlert is not a function

I think the problem is that the dialog code executes outside the web part context and hence does not know about the function available in the webpart context.

How can I use the button click to run within the webpart context?

Here is the Dialog code.

```
    public render(): void {

    this.domElement.innerHTML = AlertTemplate.templateHtml;
    const dialogOptions: JQueryUI.DialogOptions = {
      width: "50%",
      height: "auto",
      buttons: {
        "Subscribe": function (e) {
          this.addAlert("Yes");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "No Thanks": function (e) {
          console.log("moo");
          this.addAlert("No");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Ask me later": function (e) {
          this.addAlert("Ask Me Later");
          jQuery(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    };

    jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog(dialogOptions);
    jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
  }
```

**function addAlert**

```
public addAlert(status: string): void {
var url = "/sites/" + this.context.pageContext.site.id + "/lists";
var listId = "";
var email = this.getCurrentUserEmail();
var recordExists = false;
let item: SubscriptionListItem;
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    client
      .api(url)
      .top(1)
      .filter("equals=(displayName, 'Subscriptions'")
      .version("v1.0")
      .get((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res);
        listId = res.id;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` reference inside the context of the event handler is not a reference to your react component.  `this` in that context is usually the object that triggered the event, such as the clicked button.  In JSX you can use [binding](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to bind your event handler to the context of your component:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   `bind` `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be undefined
>   when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without ()
>   after it, such as `onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that
>   method.

There are multiple techniques in the above referenced article for binding your event handlers to your component's `this` context, but here is one example:

```
public onDialogButtonClick(status: string, e): void {
    this.addAlert(status);
    jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog("close");
}

public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = AlertTemplate.templateHtml;
    const dialogOptions: JQueryUI.DialogOptions = {
      width: "50%",
      height: "auto",
      buttons: {
        "Subscribe": this.onDialogButtonClick.bind(this, "Subscribe"),
        "No Thanks": this.onDialogButtonClick.bind(this, "No Thanks"),
        "Ask me later": this.onDialogButtonClick.bind(this, "Ask me later")
      }
    };

    jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog(dialogOptions);
    jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think this would work, however, I am getting another error when I try to close the dialog `cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`.  Any idea as to why?

Comment: nvm. Changing the code to this `jQuery('.dialog', this.domElement).dialog("close");`.  Thanks for your help.  Can you please update the code and I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: I added your new close method to the code sample.